# WCF Service Design Pattern for File Storage / Encryption

Tags: c#, wcf, design-patterns

I'm starting a project that is required to take a document (pdf, jpeg, etc) via a WCf service and store it in with encryption in a location.

My question is one of fundamental class layout / design.

My intention is to have the WCF service function (SaveDocument) create call a worker class that handles the encryption / saving. Both the encryption / saving need to be changeable for future proofing i.e. change encryption method or how / where the data is saved (DB / File). Does my design below make sense:-

```
class DocumentManager
{
    private IEncryptionService encrypt;
    private IStoreService store;

    private Document doc;

    public DocumentManager(Document _doc)
    {
        encrypt = new XXXEncryptionService();
        store = new FileStoreService();
        doc = _doc;
    }

    public bool Save()
    {
        byte[] data = encrypt.Encrypt(doc.data);
        return store.Save(data);
    }
}

class IEncryptionService
{
    public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] stream);
    public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] stream);
}

class IStoreManager
{
    public bool Save(byte[] stream);       
}
```

Is there any use in the DocumentManager class being interfaced? I assume it would help for unit testing? Any other recommendations?

Many Thanks

Comment: I'd inject the two services into the constructor, and pass the document into the Save method.  That way you won't have to touch the DocumentManager class when you add new storage or encryption services.  It also allows you to mock things nicely for testing.  I am assuming you'll flesh out the error handling on the services.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, seems obvious! Yeas, error handling etc will be in the services. I just wanted to get a bit of feedback on the design before I went into detail. Thanks again :).